# jQuery Toggle animation não está a funcionar

Tags: jquery, animação, toggle

Eu tenho este código, e gostaria que fizesse toggle ao click mas não está a funcionar. Alguma dica sff?

HTML:

```
<body>
<img id="topBar" src="imgs/topBar.png">
<div id ="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" src="imgs/logo.jpg"></a>
        <a href="index.php"><img id="logoMob" src="imgs/logo.jpg"></a>
        <div id ="btMob"><h1>MENU</h1></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Linguas.php">Línguas</a></li>
            <li><a href="Cursos.php">Cursos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Learning_Portuguese.php">Learning Portuguese</a></li>
            <li><a href="Testemunhos.php">Testemunhos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Sobre_nos.php">Sobre nós</a></li>
            <li><a href="FAQ.php">FAQ</a></li>
            <li id ="cont"><a>contactos</a><img src="imgs/arrow.png"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border-left: 1500px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -1500px;
}
#logoMob {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
#btMob {
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 63px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
#logo {
        display: none;
    }
#logoMob {
        display: inline;
    }
    #btMob {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
       $('#logoMob, #btMob').click(function() {
          $('nav ul').stop(true).animate({
            left:"328px"
          }, 300, 'linear');
        }, function() {
          $('nav ul').stop(true).animate({
            left:"0"
          }, 300, 'linear');
        });
```

Comment: Coloca o html, assim não é fácil ajudar...

Comment: Tem razão, desculpe, já editei

Comment: Dica: no Brasil não se usa *Se Faz Favor*, muito menos *sff*. De todos modos, "alguma dica sff?" não é lá uma grande pergunta ;)

Comment: Ok, mas eu não sou do Brasil. Sou de Portugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `.click()` do jQuery não suporta mais do que uma função como parametro. O `.hover()` é que tem essa opção para o "hover-out".

O que você pode fazer é criar uma flad/bandeira: http://jsfiddle.net/tm27p/

```
var bandeira = false;
$('#logoMob, #btMob').click(function () {
    $('nav ul').stop(true).animate({
        left: (bandeira = (!bandeira)) ? "328px" : "0px"
    }, 300, 'linear');
});
```

Comment: Muito obgado, pensava que o click tinha o mesmo funcionamento do hover

Answer (score 0):

Não funciona porque ao fazer o click está executando a segunda função:

```
 $('#logoMob, #btMob').click(function() {

     //NÃO EXECUTA ESSE TRECHO AO FAZER CLICK
      $('nav ul').stop(true).animate({
        left:"328px"
      }, 300, 'linear');
    }, function() {

      //EXECUTA ESSE TRECHO AO FAZER CLICK
      $('nav ul').stop(true).animate({
        left:"0"
      }, 300, 'linear');
    });
```